# Vagrant and Docker not playing nice

Tags: macos, docker, vagrant

**Update:** I have uninstalled both Vagrant and Docker, and will accept any answer that helps me re-install both of them in such a way that:

1. I can run Vagrant without any dependency on Docker whatsoever; and
2. I can run Docker without any dependency on Vagrant whatsoever; and
3. I can run Vagrant and use Docker as the backing provider

If you look at the Vagrant source code, you'll see that my error comes from [this line of code](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/cb51b4fe7f92232ff9cf12f93e1207be619b1405/lib/vagrant/environment.rb#L382), which, for VirtualBox providers, comes from [this `usable` method](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/cb51b4fe7f92232ff9cf12f93e1207be619b1405/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb#L8) raising an error. That `usable` method raises an error if it thinks that VirtualBox has an invalid version (`VirtualBoxInvalidVersion`) or if its not detected on the local system (`VirtualBoxNotDetected`).

Not being a Ruby dev, it's now getting difficult for me to figure out how Vagrant is deciding to throw either of those two errors. But I think I'm getting closer to figuring out why Docker is hosing my Vagrant/VirtualBox config.

---

**Original question:**

Mac here. A few days ago I installed [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) and VirtualBox like so:

```
brew cask install virtualbox
brew cask install vagrant
brew cask install vagrant-manager
```

...which got it Vagrant up and running no problem whatsoever. I was able to `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32; vagrant up` and everything looked like it was running perfect (`hashicorp/precise32` uses VirtualBox by default).

Then last night I installed [Docker](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_three/), which also requires VirtualBox, and got it up and running with no problem whatsoever. I was even able to get the `whalesay` container examples working. So far so good.

Today I went to go play around in Vagrant, and it looks like my Docker install hosed my Vagrant/VirtualBox configuration.

*Now*, when I run `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32` on an empty directory, and then run `vagrant up`, I get:

```
myuser@mymac:~/sandbox/myapp$vagrant up
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

So then I tried specifying the provider type, even though I shouldn't have to, just to see what happens:

```
myuser@mymac:~/sandbox/myapp$vagrant up --provider=VirtualBox
The provider 'VirtualBox' could not be found, but was requested to
back the machine 'cortex'. Please use a provider that exists.
```

And just for good measure, running `vagrant -v` produces `Vagrant 1.7.2` as output.

Any ideas what went awry and what the fix is?

Comment: I got similar problem after install docker toolbox, and fix after run this command `rm -r ~/.vagrant.d/plugins.json ~/.vagrant.d/gems`

Comment: Thanks @BMW but this didn't work for me.

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04 is not suggested to play with docker, because docker requires Linux kernel 3.13+. Although you can run ``sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-trusty`` to upgrade kernel in it, I still suggest you to use Ubuntu 14.04 instead.

Comment: Seems you have something wrong with virtualbox awareness, try to download and install it manually.

Comment: How did you install Docker? Did you use the [OS X installer from the Docker site](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/)? Perhaps reinstall Vagrant, then instal Docker — but this time do a customised install and _don't_ install VirtualBox (see [step 4's screenshot](https://docs.docker.com/mac/step_one/)).

Comment: I believe Vagrant looks for a env variable VBOX_INSTALL_PATH, have you looked a this? It may be Windows only however

Comment: Now that Docker doesn't need VirtualBox on the Mac, Vagrant still insists on using it.

Answer (score 2):

Vagrant cares about case (at least Vagrant 1.8.1 does), so use lower case for the provider name:

```
vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
```

I think the 1.8.1 error message is much more helpful:

```
$ vagrant up --provider=VirtualBox  # NOTE: this is the WRONG capitalization
An active machine was found with a different provider. Vagrant
currently allows each machine to be brought up with only a single
provider at a time. A future version will remove this limitation.
Until then, please destroy the existing machine to up with a new
provider.

Machine name: default
Active provider: virtualbox
Requested provider: VirtualBox
```

You may also be able to set a default provider in your Vagrantfile.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, and fixed it by updating Vagrant to the latest version (had 1.7.2, updated to 1.8.1).

Comment: This - as of now, 1.7.2 is bologna, it's all about that 1.8.1 nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working, but have no idea what the actual solution was.

1. Uninstall both Vagrant and Docker
2. Reinstall Vagrant manually (not via `brew/cask`)
3. Reinstall Docker from [this link](https://www.docker.com/toolbox)
4. Use [this `Vagrantfile` to confirm](https://github.com/bubenkoff/vagrant-docker-example) that your Vagrant-Docker-VirtualBox are all working together nicely

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce the problem.  However, I read a bit of the source code from Vagrant's VirtualBox provider.  It sounds like it probably couldn't find `VBoxManage` in `$PATH`.  It should be located at `/usr/bin/VBoxManage`, even when installed via Homebrew.  Chances are your $PATH variable was incorrect, or VBoxManage was somewhere else.

Other readers who have the same problem should:

- Check `/etc/paths` to ensure that `/usr/bin` is listed, along with all the other directories typically found in $PATH.
- Look for a file named `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`.  Mac OS X does not ship with either of those files by default, but some users add them to customize bash, and some programs may attempt to automatically edit/create them.  Be wary of any lines that look like `export PATH=...`.  On OS X, changes to $PATH should be made in `/etc/paths` and `/etc/paths.d/*`, not in a bash script.
- Run `type -a VBoxManage` to see all the known locations of executables named `VBoxManage`.  There could be a stray binary somewhere that's taking precedence over the real binary.